# Call dll in safe mode

Tags: c++, dll, exception

In my project I need to call many third-party apps. I am searching for a way for call that part in a safe way.

If I call those in separate process I can isolate my main application from third-party apps faults. But I want to find a way to have this isolation in call those DLLs. maybe I can call DLLs in sandbox ( but I don't know how, if you help me how :d ).

I think about .Net AppDomain but my project is written by C++, and I can not find any concept for AppDomain in C++.

I will be happy if you can help me to find a efficient way for achieve this.

Comment: you want to implement a generic dll loader that will load the specified third-party dll, and talk to the host process via RPC. Not sure whether such open source program already exists or not, but you might want to look into it.

Comment: @JosephH: Not sure why you need to implement a generic DLL loader; the Windows one is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an existing Windows mechanism for this, COM. With the setting `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`, a DLL COM component is loaded in the COM surrogate process `DllHost.EXE`, and a COM proxy is created in your process. DllHost.EXE is your sandbox; any fault there will not crash the proxy in your process.

If the third-party components use a non-COM interface, you might need to add a thin COM wrapper yourself.